Проблема выполнения функции на PythonAnywhere
У меня есть подключение к БД для приложения на Flask, и изначально там создаётся переменная __factory = None. Потом её возвращает функция, и в редакторе у меня всё работает нормально, но вот на PythonAnywhere она не хочет возвращать None.
Код и код подключения прилагаю:
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

SqlAlchemyBase = orm.declarative_base()

__factory = None


def global_init(db_file):
    global __factory

    if __factory:
        return

    if not db_file or not db_file.strip():
        raise Exception("Необходимо указать файл базы данных.")

    conn_str = f'sqlite:///{db_file.strip()}?check_same_thread=False'
    print(f"Подключение к базе данных по адресу {conn_str}")

    engine = sa.create_engine(conn_str, echo=False)
    __factory = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    from . import __all_models

    SqlAlchemyBase.metadata.create_all(engine)


def create_session() -> Session:
    global __factory
    return __factory()  # подключение

 db_session.global_init("db/users.sqlite")  # Подключение к БД

